# Page collapse when linking CSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

suddenly when I worked on a project today my page just collapsed. It looked like this: [image]

I went straight back to dreamweaver and hit cmd+z to go back a step or two. But did not find any problem at all. Though my page continues to looks miserble.
The moment this happened I worked with some database coding like POST/GET request but also some java script.

I tried to redo my CSS file but still it refuses to work.

Here is my code to one page, I pretty much use the same code on the other 2 pages as well.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Mountain</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="allcontent">

<div>
 <ul id="cssmenu"><!--Includes menu-->
             <?php include ("menu.php");?>




      </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">

<header><img src="mountain.jpg"></header>
<hr>
<div id="left">

<script>

var thumbs = ["thumb1", "thumb2", "thumb3", "thumb4", "thumb5"];

function myHandler(target, event){
//
// Thumbs management och mousemove
  if(event.type == 'mouseover'){
//
// Clear all thumbs
    for( var count in thumbs ){
      $('#'+thumbs[count]).attr("src","stjärna.png");
    }   
//
// Show thumbs_up upto mouse position
    for( var count in thumbs ){
      $('#'+thumbs[count]).attr("src","star-iconyellow.png");
      if(thumbs[count] == target.id) break;
    }
  }
}

$("#thumb1").live('mouseover click', function(event){
  myHandler(this, event);
});
$("#thumb2").live('mouseover click', function(event){
  myHandler(this, event);
});
$("#thumb3").live('mouseover click', function(event){
  myHandler(this, event);
});
$("#thumb4").live('mouseover click', function(event){
  myHandler(this, event);
});
$("#thumb5").live('mouseover click', function(event){
  myHandler(this, event);
});

$("#rating-area").live('mouseleave', function(){
// Clear all thumbs when mouse leaves the rating area
    for( var count in thumbs ){
      $('#'+thumbs[count]).attr("src","stjärna.png");
    } 
});

</script>

            <?php
            if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

        //Kontrollerar att uppladdad bild är av rätt typ (JPEG) och att storleken
            //inte överstiger en viss storlek - i det här fallet väldigt stor...
                if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] ==
                        "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)) {
                        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                            echo "Errormessage: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                        } else {

                            //Kontrollerar att en bild med samma namn inte redan finns i 
                            //katalogen dit bilden skall flyttas
                            if (file_exists("bilder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " alrady exists. Pick another name please.";

                            } else {

                            //Flyttar filen till rätt katalog      
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "bilder/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                            //Spar namn på originalbild och miniatyr i variabler
                            $storedfile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                            $thumbnail = "thumb_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

                            //Maximal storlek i höjd och bredd för miniatyr
                            $width_thumbnail = 250;
                            $height_thumbnail = 80;


                            //Läser in originalstorleken på den uppladdade bilden, och spar 
                            //den i variablerna width_orig, height_orig
                            list($width_thumbnail_orig, $height_thumbnail_orig) = getimagesize('bilder/' . $storedfile);

                            //Räknar ut förhållandet mellan höjd och bredd (sk "ratio")
                            //Detta för att kunna få samma höjd- breddförhållande på miniatyren
                            $ratio_orig = $width_thumbnail_orig / $height_thumbnail_orig;                                      

                            //Räknar ut storlek på miniatyr
                            if ($width_thumbnail / $height_thumbnail > $ratio_orig) {
                                $width_thumbnail = $height_thumbnail * $ratio_orig;
                                $height_thumbnail = $width_thumbnail / $ratio_orig;
                            } else {
                                $height_thumbnail = $width_thumbnail / $ratio_orig;
                                $width_thumbnail = $height_thumbnail * $ratio_orig;
                            }

                            //Skapar en ny bild miniatyrbild med rätt storlek
                            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width_thumbnail, $height_thumbnail);
                            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('bilder/' . $storedfile);
                            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_thumbnail, $height_thumbnail, $width_thumbnail_orig, $height_thumbnail_orig);

                            //Sparar miniatyr
                            imagejpeg($image_p, 'bilder/' . $thumbnail);

                            echo "<h3>Image uploaded</h3>\n";
                            echo "<a href='bilder/$storedfile' title='Öppna originalbild'><img src='bilder/thumb_$storedfile' alt='$storedfile' /></a>\n";

                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else {
                        // Här hamnar man om det inte är JPEG/bildfil för stor
                        echo "No image larger than 500kb.";
                    }
            } // Slut på isset(FILE)
            ?>


    </div><!-- /uploadform -->


</div>
<div id="right">



<h4>Mountains</h4>
<p>Here you will find all the pictures uploaded that contains a mountain in it "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
</div>


<div id="mitten">

<p> <a href="mountain.php?order=uppladdare">Uploader</a>  -  <a href="mountain.php?order=date">Date</a></p>

<div id="uploadform">
    <form action="mountain.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000" />
        <label for="file"><strong>Filename:</strong></label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="text" name="uppladdare" placeholder="Uploader:" title="What's your name?"/>
        <input type="text" name="titel" placeholder="Title" title="Give a title to your piece of work"/>
        <input type="text" name="history" placeholder="History" title="Tell us the story behind your image. Where is it taken, etc."/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
<!--Function adding tooltip to input-->

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(document).tooltip();
        }); 
    </script>
<?php
//Send data to databae
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user1", "test1", "tutorial");

    $stored_file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $file = "";

    $query = "INSERT INTO mountains (filname, uppladdare, titel, History)
VALUES ('$stored_file','$_POST[uppladdare]','$_POST[titel]','$_POST[history]')";
    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $query))
        ;
}
?>
<?php

error_reporting(0);
$order = "";

if ($_GET['order']) {
    if ($_GET['order'] == "date") {
        $order = " ORDER BY date DESC";
    }
}
if ($_GET['order']) {
    if ($_GET['order'] == "uppladdare") {
        $order = " ORDER BY uppladdare";
    }//Connections to database
}

$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user1", "test1", "tutorial");
$selectall = "SELECT * FROM mountains $order";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $selectall);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $information = ' Titel: ' . $row['titel'] . ' Uppladdare: ' . $row['uppladdare'] . ' Filnamn: ' . $row['filname'] . ' History: ' . $row['History'] . ' Datum: ' . $row['date'];

    //Echo out the form and information gathered from the database
    echo "<strong>Title: </strong>" . $row['titel'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Uploader: </strong>" . $row['uppladdare'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Imagename: </strong>" . $row['filname'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>History: </strong>" . $row['History'] . "<br>";
    echo "<strong>Date: </strong>" . $row['date'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    $original = $row['filname'];

    echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='massoravbilder' href='bilder/$original'> <img src='bilder/thumb_" . $row['filname'] . "' alt='$information' /></a>" . "<br>";
}
?>





</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('li a').click(function(){
        $.get($(this).prop('href'), function(data){
            $('#allcontent').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
 </script>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS file looks like:

```
body    {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;



}

#content{
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


#left   {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    margin:10px;

}
#right  {
    float:right;
    width:350px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:left;
}

h3  {
    text-align:center;
}

header  img {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
}

#cssmenu    li  {
    list-style-type:none;

}
#cssmenu    li  a   {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:grey;
    margin:4px;


}

#cssmenu    a:hover {
    background-color:grey;
    color:white;

}

.inlogg {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;


}

#mitten {
    width:200px;

}

#footer

{ 
width: 100%;
height:20px;
background-color:#999;
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
top:97.5%;
border-top: solid #000;
}

img:nth-child(1){
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  img:nth-child(2){
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  img:nth-child(3){
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
  }
  img:nth-child(4){
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
  }

  div {
// Rounded corners with border and padding of the rating area div
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative; 
    top: 100px; 
    left: 200px; 

    border: 2px solid grey; padding:10px; 
  }
  .shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
  }

  #resultat{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      position:relative;
  }
```

As I said, it worked but suddenly it just did not.

I've been sittin for almost 6 hours trying to solve why I can't link a CSS file now. I have deleted the other link/scripts in the head section and tried only with this CSS link. But nothing worked.

Please help me solve this.

If I forgot anything please tell me.

Comment: Try clearing your floats. Add `clear: both;` to `h3  {}` and `#cssmenu a:hover {}`

Comment: Did not work. The only thing that changed was the upload application which mvoed more to the middle.

Comment: Consider using version control from now on, it will make your life incredibly easier.

Comment: Version control of what? Links? Dreamweaver?

Comment: Version control for the whole project. Like SVN or Git for example. You *check-in/commit* your files to a central place (Well in SVN you do. You can commit locally with Git and then push.). That way you can always roll-back. At the moment, how would you revert to the code you had yesterday, 2 or 4 weeks ago? Version control is an absolute must (I think) for any project.

Comment: I haven't started with project that large yet. But thanks for advice.
Im still having trouble with this CSS link. Any idea?

Comment: It doesn't matter how large the project is, or how many people are working on it. I use version control if it's just a throwaway 1 person project.

Comment: I see your point, but each step I save my project, view it in a webbrowser and if something went wrong I go cmd+z.
I dont think the program would have done any different this time. But I will keep it in mind for my next project.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your DIV after the "allcontent" div. The layout goes back to something recognizable.  It should be:

```
<div id="allcontent">

 <!-- REMOVE THIS  <div>   -->

 <ul id="cssmenu"><!--Includes menu-->
             <?php include ("menu.php");?>
```

There are probably some layout issues.  Try running it through this:

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. Nor did the validation say something.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the PHP/JavaScript and simply tweaking your basic layout?  Should yield a result quickly...

Comment: Yeh, but it's still not working. Can it be a bug in dreamweaver?

Comment: Probably not!  Try it here, in an external environment: http://cssdesk.com/  And remove all your JS and PHP!  Your layout is not super complex.  You will find the culprit.  Just keep removing stuff until it works.